# Issue with violin plots in ggplot2 not plotting correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

I have a dataframe `masterlist` which consists of a couple of other merged datasets/dataframes of excel files that track the year and specific counters of certain events happening from 2013 to 2021 (for example, in one dataset `data2013`, the file tracks how many outages occured for a company in the year 2013, eg 122 outages).

```
structure(list(DataYear = c("2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
"2013"), UtilityNumber = c("97", "108", "155", "162", "195", 
"207"), UtilityName = c("Adams Electric Coop", "Adams-Columbia Electric Coop", 
"Agralite Electric Coop", "Aiken Electric Coop Inc", "Alabama Power Co", 
"City of Alameda"), State = c("IL", "WI", "MN", "SC", "AL", "CA"
), Ownership = c("Cooperative", "Cooperative", "Cooperative", 
"Cooperative", "Investor Owned", "Municipal"), SAIDIWithMed = c("223", 
"143", "1142", NA, NA, "16.48"), SAIFIWithMed = c("1.81", "1.093", 
"3", NA, NA, "6.8000000000000005E-2"), CAIDIWithMed = c("123.20442", 
"130.83257", "380.66667000000001", NA, NA, "242.35293999999999"
), SAIDIWithoutMed = c("158", "58", "141", NA, NA, NA), SAIFIWithoutMed = c("1.35", 
"0.69099999999999995", "1", NA, NA, NA), CAIDIWithoutMed = c("117.03704", 
"83.936323999999999", "141", NA, NA, NA), SAIDIWithMedMinusLOS = c("191", 
"139", "1134", NA, NA, NA), SAIFIWithMedMinusLOS = c("1.39", 
"1.028", "2", NA, NA, NA), CAIDIMinusMed = c("137.41006999999999", 
"135.21401", "567", NA, NA, NA), NumberOfCustomers = c("8715", 
"36014", "5122", NA, NA, "34347"), OutagesAutomaticallyRecorded = c("N", 
"Y", "N", NA, NA, "N")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My next step is to simply display violin plots (and other plots similar to violin plots) for one specific column of data called `SAIDIWithMed`. I type this code out in jupyter, but I get a plot that doesn't seem to look correct for me:

`p <- ggplot(masterlist_test, aes(x=DataYear, y=SAIDIWithMed)) + geom_violin()`

`p`

[image]

All of the graphs data points are conjoined to the left of the graph, where it's supposed to be located between the x axis of 2013 to 2021. I'm wondering what could possibly be the issue of why it looks wrong, and if I'm missing any fundamental statistics-related or r-related practices. Thank you.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of data but provide a sufficient sample to copy&paste and work on: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Pasting the output of `dput(your_data)` is a convenient way for this.

Comment: Your first screenshot clearly shows that all columns are character strings, even those that should be numeric to create a violin plot.

Comment: @Roland you meant factor as well, right? I converted the DataYear (x value) into a factor and the y value into numeric and that supposedly fixed it.

Comment: ggplot2 will convert character strings to a factor variable automatically.